# Centering menu rendered with UL, LI

Tags: wordpress-theming

Given a menu created by a Wordpress Theme "Twenty Eleven" with HTML tags UL and LI, how might we go about centering the LI items. The client would like to have the individual items centered when the display is narrowed and the menu consumes two lines.

[image]

Single line menu

[image]

Split line menu, not-yet centered

[image]

CSS for `#access UL`

```
#access ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

CSS for LI

```
#access li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `text-align: center;` and `width: 100%;` in `#access ul`
2. Switch `float: left;` to `display: inline;` in `#access li`. You'll possibly need to stablish paddings, a width or a height for a better viewing.

Comment: If display: inline doesn't achieve it, try inline-block. Any element inside the li's will need a display: block (I suppose you'll use <a> elements)